# Laravel API on same IP with a different Port on nginx

Tags: laravel, api, nginx, port, config

I have a VM on which a nginx server is running. Now there is only one instance running and I want a second, for my Laravel API. The VM has Ubuntu server 16.04 as operating system.

Now I have created a second file in / etc / nginx / sites-available and linked to sites-enabled. In the hosts, I have also created, for testing purposes, a line that is 127.0.0.1 example.com. If I call this with curl example.com:8000. Do I get back a website in the terminal. Since I discover my folder name there again and again, I assume that everything is correct.

Now I would like to do that from the outside. I want to be able to access my Laravel API outside the vm with a different port.

I thought that works if I have it just like in the default file. So I have specified as server name _. That was not the solution.

With 192.168.2.110 I still get the WordPress page. But with 192.168.2.110:8000 no page is found. Finally, the IP should also serve only for REST purposes in Angular. But so I know if it works too, I should see the Laravel home page in the Public folder.

I was following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 8000 default_server;
    listen [::]:8000 default_server;


    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/MT_Backend_Iventorysystem/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    # Following location added to handle WordPress correctly
    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robot.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way:

In App/Providers/RouteServiceProvider:

```
public function map()
{
   switch(request()->getPort())
   {
      case 80:
      case 8080:
      case 443:
          $this->mapWebRoutes();
          break;
     // choose a port that is not used by another server
      case 8975:
          $this->mapApiRoutes();
          break;
    }
}
```

In ngnix

```
server {
       listen 8975;
       server_name YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME;
       root '/path/to/your/application/public/;
       ...
```